# AngularJS - Focusing an input element when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: angularjs

Is there a cleaner way of delegating focus to an element when a checkbox is clicked. Here's the dirty version I hacked:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggled()">
    <input id="name">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.value = "Something";
    $scope.toggled = function() {
        console.debug('toggled');
        $timeout(function() {
            $('#name').focus();
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U4jvE/8/

Comment: A delay value of 0 (instead of 100) should also work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

how about this one ? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/84NRZHlGeL3LqS4XgTGY)

```
 $scope.$watch('isChecked', function(newV){
      newV && $('#name').focus();
    },true);
```

@asgoth and @Mark Rajcok are correct. We should use directive. I was just lazy.

Here is the directive version. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/84NRZHlGeL3LqS4XgTGY) I think one good reason to make it as directive is you can reuse this thing.

so in your html you can just assign different modals to different sets

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isCheckedN">
<input xng-focus='isCheckedN'>


directive('xngFocus', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.xngFocus, 
         function (newValue) { 
            newValue && element.focus();
         },true);
      };    
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Another directive implementation (that does not require jQuery), and borrowing some of @maxisam's code:

```
myApp.directive('focus', function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
       scope.$watch('focusCheckbox', 
         function (newValue) { 
            newValue && element[0].focus()
         })
    }      
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="focusCheckbox">
<input ng-model="name" focus>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/LZKkw/).

Since this directive doesn't create an isolate scope (or a child scope), the directive assumes the scope has a `focusCheckbox` property defined.

Comment: @maxisam, I like the attribute you added in your answer.  BTW, does element.focus() work for you?  I had to use element[0].focus().

Comment: I forgot you are including jQuery, so that's why element.focus() works.  If jQuery isn't included, we have to use element[0].focus() instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make it more interesting, and support for any expression to be evaluated (not only variables), you can do this:

```
app.directive('autofocusWhen', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.autofocusWhen, function(newValue){
                if ( newValue ) {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        element.focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
     };
});
```

And your html can be a little more decoupled, like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="product.selected" />
{{product.description}}
<input type="text" autofocus-when="product.selected" />
```

Comment: Why did you use the $timeout service?

Comment: @Alpha, for some reason, in AngularJS, `$watch` expressions happen before the html re-draw, so a instant call to `element.focus();` would  focus the element and immediately lose the focus, as the scope change, and the element is redrawed. Using the `$timeout` service is a known workaround for adding the change in the queue, so it happens right after the HTML redraw.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way is to use a directive to perform the toggle:

```
app.directive('toggle', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
         selector: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('change', function() {
              $(scope.selector).focus();
              scope.$apply();
          });
      }
   }:
});
```

Your html would be sth like:

```
<input type='checkbox' toggle selector='#name'>
```

Comment: What if the selector is not unique on the page? In this case I would have many `.name`s but only one of them matches the current scope.